# Delphi + Synapse: How to check if I am still connected

Tags: delphi, ararat-synapse

I am using [`TTCPBlockSocket`](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/blcksock.TTCPBlockSocket.html) for a TCP/IP Application . The problem is that I can't determine when the connection is lost.

`GetLastError` returns 0
`Read` returns 0

But I encounter these values eaven if the application is connected so I can get it how can I be notified when the TCP/IP connection is lost.

Thanks

Comment: I'd say the [`CanRead`](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/blcksock.TBlockSocket.html#CanRead) function call passing 0 as `Timeout` parameter is what you're looking for. This function internally calls `InternalCanRead` which performs the Winsock [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) function. The `CanRead` function returns False if any error occurs.

Comment: @TLama your answer led me to the right path tough the following condition must be met to check if it is disconnected if TCPBlockSocket.CanRead(0) and TCPBlockSocket.WaitingData = 0 the disconnected := true. You can post this as an answer for me to accept

Comment: @TLama is the synapse expert !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, you can use the [`CanRead`](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/blcksock.TBlockSocket.html#CanRead) method, passing 0 to its `Timeout` parameter. This function internally performs [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for the socket and returns False when an error occurs. It should be enough to use just this method since the [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns `SOCKET_ERROR` if you lose the connection, and it causes the [`CanRead`](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/blcksock.TBlockSocket.html#CanRead) method return False as a result. So I think, it's enough to check if the socket connection is alive this way:

```
function IsSocketAlive(ASocket: TTCPBlockSocket): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ASocket.CanRead(0);
end;
```

Comment: Nope is not enough test it yourself +1 for this

Comment: The `WaitingData` method (as you added) returns the amount of data pending in the network's input buffer, and if that internal `ioctlsocket` function call doesn't fail with the `SOCKET_ERROR` and returns the pending data amount at the time when your connection is already lost, then it doesn't reflect your needs. Or am I wrong ? (unfortunately, I can't test it now)

Answer (score 1):

As opC0de says, to check if the client is still connected you need to both check  TCPBlockSocket.CanRead(0) and TCPBlockSocket.WaitingData = 0

```
function IsSocketAlive(ASocket: TTCPBlockSocket): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (ASocket.Socket = INVALID_SOCKET) or ((ASocket.WaitingData = 0) and ASocket.CanRead(0));
end;
```

I'm using this way in my projects so I can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was using kattunga's answer, but encountered a lot of false positive triggers during my stress test. My assumption is that the packet will sometimes arrive at a server between WaitingData and CanRead conditions, leading to server thinking that a socket is dead.
I changed the order of conditions and problem was gone.

```
function TTCPSynWorkThread.IsSocketDead(ASocket: TTCPBlockSocket): boolean;
begin 
  Result := (ASocket.Socket = INVALID_SOCKET) or (ASocket.CanRead(0) and (ASocket.WaitingData = 0));
end;
```