# Closing a connection and re-opening with Synapse in Lazarus

Tags: sockets, tcp, lazarus, fpc

I'm using the Synapse library with Lazarus and I'm trying to switch a `TCPBlockSocket` connection between two different IP addresses.

I create the Socket connection with:

```
mySocket:=TTCPBlockSocket.Create
```

I then connect to the first IP address with:

```
mySocket.Connect(firstIPaddress,portNumber);
```

This works fine, but if I try to switch to the second IP address with

```
mySocket.Connect(secondIPaddress,portNumber);
```

any data I send with `mySocket.SendString()` is still sent to `firstIPaddress`.

I have tried `.Destroy`ing `mySocket` and recreating it but I get crashes (I check if `mySocket` is assigned and if it is do a `.Destory` before recreating the `TCPBlockSocket` object - but that seems a bit severe anyway.

Is there a correct way to disconnect and then reconnect an exiting `TCPBlockSocket` to a different IP address?

And is there an easy way to test if a `TCPBLockSocket` has an active and working connection?

Comment: I've had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045943/delphi-synapse-how-to-check-if-i-am-still-connected for the second question above, but `(mySocket.Socket = INVALID_SOCKET) or ((mySocket.WaitingData = 0) and mySocket.CanRead(0))` always returns false even though I have a good connection...

Comment: After further investigation it seems that it is the `.CanRead(0)` that is returning `false` every time and causing the call to return `false` - even though the connection is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious when you find it...

You need to call `mySocket.CloseSocket()` before calling `.Connect` with the new IP address and port.

(Still problems checking if an opened connection is still open and working though - as per my comment to the OP)